# Find HREF and make h3 title click through to that link

Tags: jquery

My HTML

```
    //box one
<div class="blog-module">
<h3>Title of Blog</h3>
<div class="blog entry">
Each blog post in here.
</div>
<div class="blog entry">
Each blog post in here.
</div>
<div class="more">
<a href="link.com">Read more</a>
</div>
</div>

//box two
<div class="blog-module">
<h3>Title of Blog</h3>
<div class="blog entry">
Each blog post in here.
</div>
<div class="blog entry">
Each blog post in here.
</div>
<div class="more">
<a href="link.com">Read more</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Using jQuery, I'd like to find each **.more a** href and make the **h3** tag within each **.blog-module** div click through to it. 
Thanks

Comment: You forgot to post the JavaScript you tried that didn't work. Also, in your example, the second div block closes differently than the first. Is that intentional?

Comment: You have one too many `</div>` which makes it really difficult for anybody to answer if they can't be sure of how your code is actually structured. If you indented your HTML, it would be much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.more a', '.blog-module').each(function(index, link){
    var $link = $(link);
    var $headingLink = $('<a/>');
    $headingLink.attr('href', $link.attr('href'));
    var $heading = $('h3', $link.parent().parent());
    $headingLink.append($heading.clone());
    $heading.replaceWith($headingLink);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for replying James.
I've actually worked out my own solution which is as follows. I meant to post this originally (thought I had) but it wasn't working. It is now:

`$('.blog-module').each(function(){
    var SP_Link = $(this).find(".more a").attr('href');
    var SP_Module_Name = $(this).find("h3").text();
     $(this).find("h3").replaceWith ('<h3><a href="'+SP_Link+'">'+SP_Module_Name+'</a></h3>');

});`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.blog-module').each(function(){
var SP_Link = $(this).find(".more a").attr('href');
var SP_Module_Name = $(this).find("h3").text();
$(this).find("h3").replaceWith ('<h3><a href="'+SP_Link+'">'+SP_Module_Name+'</a></h3>');
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tag6ardk/)